# If the transformation $T$ that transposes every matrx is linear, which of the following are true

Tags: linear-algebra

a)
$T^{2}$ = identity transformation

I think this is true: if you take the transpose of a transposed matrix, then it goes back to what you started with.

b)
The kernel of T is the zero matrix

I think this is false. Here's a counterexample: let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
0 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$ Then $A^{T}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$, so the kernel of $T$ is the span of $(0,1)$, not necessarily the zero matrix.

c)
Every matrix is in the range of $T$

I am inclined to say that this is false, but I can't come up with a counterexample for this. Could someone help me out?

d)
$T(M)= -M$ is impossible.

I'm inclined to say that this is true. Since the transpose just changes the rows into columns and that does not involve changing the sign. However, I am still a bit skeptical. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A^T = B^T$.

Assuming $T$ is linear, we can re-write this as:

$T(A) - T(B) = T(A - B) = 0$

and converting back: $(A - B)^T = 0$

This means every column of $(A - B)^T$ is $0$, so every row of $A - B$ is $0$, that is:

$A - B = 0$, so $A = B$. Hence $T$ is injective, and thus has trivial kernel.

Part (c) is actually equivalent to (b). Do you see why?

For part (d) consider the matrix:

$M = \begin{bmatrix}0&a\\-a&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

(a) looks good.

For (b): the span of $(0,1)$ is the kernel of the *matrix* $A^T$, but *not the operator* $T$. The kernel of $T$ should be a matrix $A$ which satisfies $T(A) = A^T = 0$.

For (c): Write down a random matrix and try to figure out something that will transpose to give you that matrix.

For (d): Write out the four equations for $T(M) = -M$ in the 2-by-2 case and try to solve them. What happens?

Comment: Could you elaborate on (d)? How can a transpose of a matrix switch signs?